# *ngFor loop ul list sorted in categories based on model values

Tags: angular

Let's say I have model:

```
export class CarDetails {
    Name: string;
    Favourite: boolean;
}
```

I have an array of objects:

```
[{
  Name: "Toyota",
  Favourite: false
},{
  Name: "Skoda",
  Favourite: true
},
{
  Name: "Volvo",
  Favourite: true
},{
  Name: "Honda",
  Favourite: false
}]
```

My goal is to create loop with the array in such way:

```
===Favourite===
Skoda
Volvo
===Other===
Honda
Toyota
```

In code way it should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <div>Favourite</div>
    <li>Skoda</li>
    <li>Volvo</li>
    <div>Other</div>
    <li>Honda</li>
    <li>Toyota</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way I could do this with angular *ngFor loop? I found something about templateOutlets but it didn't work in my example, here is the code:

```
<ul #carList>
  <div>Favourite</div>
  <div *ngTemplateOutlet="favourite"></div>
  <div>Other</div>
  <div *ngTemplateOutlet="other"></div>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let data of Cars;let i = index;">
    <ng-template #favourite> // how to make the this in dynamic way - if favourite, then favourite, else other
      <li>{{data.name}}</li>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Alternative way would be to have two lists but I am not interested of maintaining two similar objects, especially if I want to add some filter etc it will become complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use `*ngIf` and iterate with `<ng-container>`

```html
<ul>
  <div>Favourite</div>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let data of Cars">
    <li *ngIf="data.Favourite === true">
      {{data.Name}}
    </li>
  </ng-container>

  <div>Other</div>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let data of Cars">
    <li *ngIf="data.Favourite === false">
      {{data.Name}}
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Comment: this didn't answer my question how to sort it in the categories -adding there label

Comment: You can simply iterate twice to achieve it. I've update my post.

Comment: Thanks zmag but I guess i'ts not the best way to loop twice, also there are some issues with accessibility in my case (it's an autocomplete input) so still would prefer if there is any way to achieve it with templateOutlet or similar appraoch

Answer (score 0):

You can see an implementation in this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yiygwz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  readonly cars = [{
    Name: "Toyota",
    Favourite: false
  }, {
    Name: "Skoda",
    Favourite: true
  },
  {
    Name: "Volvo",
    Favourite: true
  }, {
    Name: "Honda",
    Favourite: false
  }];

  favoriteCars = this.cars.filter((a) => a.Favourite);
  nonFavoriteCars = this.cars.filter(a => !a.Favourite);
}


<div>
  ==favorites==
  <ul *ngFor="let car of favoriteCars">
    <li>{{car.Name}}</li>
  </ul>
  ==Other==
  <ul *ngFor="let car of nonFavoriteCars">
    <li>{{car.Name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Result:

```
==favorites==
Skoda
Volvo
==Other==
Toyota
Honda
```